# C/C++ Packing and Compression

Tags: c++, c, compression, archive, zlib

I'm working on a commercial project that requires a couple of files to be bundled (packed) into an archive and then compressed. Right now we have zlib in our utility library, but it doesn't look like zlib has the functionality to compress multiple files into one archive. Does anyone know of free libraries I'd be able to use for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps [libtar](http://www.feep.net/libtar/)? Also under a BSD license.

Comment: It looks like libtar is a good solution for this project. Thanks everyone for your speedy replies.

Answer (score 12):

7Zip has a [full SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) for several languages including C and C++. The compression is extremely good, albeit not very fast. The code is licensed under the LGPL.

Comment: 7Zip also has decent support for AES encryption.

Comment: Personally, I'm a fan of 7Zip, but the LGPL might cause problems in this situation.

Comment: The LZMA SDK portion of 7-Zip is in the public domain, so no LGPL concerns apply.  If you want all of 7-Zip's features (not just LZMA), then 7-Zip itself is under the LGPL, but this isn't a problem for commercial apps as long as you leave it in a DLL, include a copy of the LGPL in your distribution, and provide source upon request.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [libzip](http://nih.at/libzip/) - it's under a BSD-like licence so it should be usable in a commercial project.

Answer (score 2):

To compress multiple files into one zip archive you could use [Zipios++](http://zipios.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Also have a look at [bzip2](http://www.bzip.org/).

Comment: bzip2 cannot compress multiple files into an archive. You typically use tar to join all your files into one before giving it to bzip.